# WordPress Shortcode - Change Layout Based On Attribute

Tags: wordpress, attributes, custom-post-type, shortcode

I have the following Custom Shortcode that displays a Custom Post Type of staff members in a defined taxonomy of "type". I'm trying to add a second attribute that will allow the user to define the layout style of the output, for example columns or rows. Here is what I envision the shortcode looking like:

```
[staff type="international" style="rows"]
```

I think I have all the coding for getting the attributes, including setting the default values, but I can't seem to figure out how to get an if statement in there to alter the output. It seems like it should go right before the first "$output .=" line.

```
function get_staff($atts) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        'type' => 'international', 
        'style' => 'rows'
        ), $atts ) );

    add_filter( 'posts_orderby' , 'posts_orderby_lastname' );

    $loop = new WP_Query(
        array (
            'post_type' => 'staff',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'staff-type' => $type,
            'style' => $style
        )
    );

    remove_filter( 'posts_orderby' , 'posts_orderby_lastname' );

    if ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $output = '<div class="staff">';

        while($loop->have_posts()){
            $loop->the_post();
            $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_id());
            // Attributes Array for Featured Image Below
            $attr = array(
                                'title' => get_the_title(),
                                'alt' => get_the_title(),
                                'class' => 'img_frame'
                            );
            $output .= '
                <div class="row-fluid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; margin-bottom: 16px; padding-bottom: 16px;">
                <div class="span3">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'small', $attr) . '</div>
                <div class="span9"><h3>' . get_the_title()  . '</h3>
                ' . get_the_content() . '
            </div></div>
        ';
    }
    $output .= "</div>";
} else {
    $output = 'No Staff Meet This Criteria Yet.';
}

return $output;
};

// Create Last Name Sort For Staff Custom Post Type
function posts_orderby_lastname ($orderby_statement) 
{
  $orderby_statement = "RIGHT(post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(post_title)) - 1) ASC";
    return $orderby_statement;
}


add_shortcode('staff', 'get_staff');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways, depending on your coding style. You can check for the `style` param *before* starting to loop over posts. Another way is to do it *after* starting to loop. Sure, there's some code duplication, but it's easier to read and you'll have all the control you need over the exact markup you want to generate.

```
$output = '<div class="staff">';

if ($loop->have_posts()) {

    if($style == 'rows'){ // rows
        $output .= '<div class="layout-rows">';
        while( $loop->have_posts() ){
            // ...
        }
        $output .= "</div>";
    } elseif($style == 'columns') { // columns
        $output .= '<div class="layout-columns">';
        while( $loop->have_posts() ){
            // ...
        }
        $output .= "</div>";
    } else { // everything else
        $output .= '<div class="layout-default">';
        while( $loop->have_posts() ){
            // ...
        }
        $output .= "</div>";
    }

} else {
    $output = 'No Staff Meet This Criteria Yet.';
}

$output .= "</div>";
```

Comment: Thanks, now that I see it, it makes perfect sense. Not sure what I was doing wrong but this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Cheers. I think the issue was opening the `<div class="staff">` inside the `if` and closing it outside.